# When will Valgrind gives Output

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

When will valgrind prints its error log?

It is dumping every error into the log file at onetime.
How can I get memory lost messages instantaneously whenever I tried particular input.

Please help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with memcheck afaik. It monitors the allocation and deallocation of every memory chuck with some additional information as debugging aid. If some memory is allocated but not freed, it's probably lost. Memcheck also tracks if a piece of memory can still be referenced but checking this after every operation would be overkill I think.

Just write a script which calls your tool with valgrind with a parameter or - even better - look for a unittest framework, which supports valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

memcheck will output immediately some classes of errors. For example,
when uninitialised data is used for a jump.

'Memory leak errors' are output when a leak search is done.
By default, a leak search is done at the end of the execution of your program.

Several techniques can be used to do leak search during execution:

1. You can use vgdb from the shell.
2. You can use GDB+vgdb to put breakpoints at various places, and when a breakpoint is encountered, do a leak search. More generally, you can use any GDB command (next/step/...) and do leak search when desired.
3. Finally, you can launch leak search from your program, using a client request.

For more info, see:

http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands